# WP All Export - Get image urls seperated into an array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to export a specific xml feed for my products and what I need is to have additional_image like 3 of 4 times. additional_images with have the image url from product gallery.

WP all export has the shortcode {Image URL} and what it returns is something like this:

```
<additional_images>
https://www.website.gr/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/product1_image_a.png|https://www.website.gr/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/product1_image_b.png
</additional_images>
```

I tried to write a function

```
function test($urls) {
    $string_urls = explode("|", $urls);
    return $string_urls;
}
```

Like the explode() example in php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

I was thinking that this is going to work for this too.

When I execute the specific function I get only the first url. When I use `return $string_urls[0];` again the first url, BUT when I use `return $string_urls[1];` I get an error **PHP Error: Undefined offset: 1 on line 15 of the Functions Editor**

What I want to succeed is in every addition_image -> [test({Image URL}, {image_number})]

```
function test($urls, $number) {
    $string_urls = explode("|", $urls);
    return $string_urls[$number];
}
```

Comment: What value for `$urls` does your function actually get passed in? That probably isn't what you thought it would be.

Comment: Is there an easy way to found out? @CBroe

Comment: I am not sure if you can just write debug output to the output buffer here, whether that would actually get shown in the backend during import. If not - then write to a file, and check the contents of that afterwards.